# Error Failed to resolve recyclerview-v7 in Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, gradle

I want to add this dependency in my build.gradle file :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

when I add this and click on the Sync now, it gives me error :

```
Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7
```

and this is my build.gradle file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 

all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    api project(':MapdroidClient')
    api project(':UiUtil')
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

I know that in my observablescrollview library, there is recyclerview dependency, but I don't know why i get this error.

I searched every where and none of solutions worked. Solutions like changing order of google() and jcenter() repositories ...

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because observablescrollview uses uses `implementation` to reference the recyclerview. This new build keyword makes inner dependencies invisible for you. In most cases, you do not need them anyways.

in your case:
if you want to use them, you need to contact the authors to compile with `api` instead of `implementation` for the recyclerview reference.

If they don't do that, you have no chance to use their inner dependency.

Comment: thanks for this great help. Actually I don't really know the differences of api and implementation and I don't want to use inner dependencies, I want all my support library versions be 28.0.0. But in observablescrollview, they use version 22.2.0. And I got error mixing version can lead to runtime error.

Comment: what you heard is true. And that is the reason why this special case is a good one to use the ``api`` keyword. Glad I could help. Accept the answer please if it solved your problem.

Comment: no , I changed implementation to api for 3 of my libraries but I got same error

Comment: Yes you are right. My bad. The ``api`` keyword is not necessary in YOUR build.gradle file but in the build file of the observable scrollview. If they used ``implementation``, the reference is hidden for you. You can't use it.
THEY need to open the reference for you by linking recyclerview as ``api``.

Comment: and I haven't access to that library, I just use it :(

Comment: Let me add, I had a similar problem (mismatching library versions) when adding google ads library. For me, it ended up in using the androidX framework, where all dependencies are correct. If you can not / want not do that, you need to reduce your 28.0.0 version down to the version of their library to avoid conflicts.